# Setting up linux with enought swap space to hibernate

Tags: debian, system-installation, hibernate

Using Debian wheezy graphical install I want to ensure I have enough swap space to hibernate, what are the simplest steps to achieve this?

Comment: The mkswap utility might do the trick for you. Take a look at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/swap-space.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to ensure I have enough swap space to hibernate, what are the simplest steps to achieve this?

You'll want at least as much swap space as you have RAM.  I'd recommend 50% more if you are used to using most of your memory, since while I have not found any official number, I seem to recall it refusing to work occasionally when they are roughly equal in size.